# What happens when a "ground effect" plane approaches the sound barrier?

Tags: aircraft-physics, supersonic, ground-effect, hypersonic, fluid-dynamics

Does the shock wave inhibit or contribute to lift? What is the ideal speed to fly near or on the speed of sound while using the ground effect?

Comment: very complicated question. the proximity of the ground means that the shock wave will bounce off the ground and come back at the underside of the wing and strongly interfere with airflow there.

Comment: This is a problem they must have solved for [supersonic cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThrustSSC)

Comment: To add to the complexity, in proximity to a wall, the shocks don't even reflect nicely like a tennis ball, you have very complex shock triple-points (not to be confused with phase triple-points) formed near the walls. This has very drastic effects on the boundary layer as well. There's lots of interesting CFD pics of landspeed record cars, like here: https://info.pointwise.com/webinar-attempting-break-land-speed-record